# How to insert src to iframe in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, iframe, src, sanitization

I know this question has been asked many times already but I tried to use all the suggested ways and nothing helped me. I'm tring to insert src attribute to iframe in angular but the src disappeared.

controller.ts:

```
  iframeUrl:SafeResourceUrl
userName='hh'
    constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
      ngOnInit() {
        this.iframeUrl=this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('/'+this.userName+'/preview')
    }
```

html:

```
<iframe src="{{iframeUrl}}" frameborder="0" style="width: 100%;height: -webkit-fill-available;min-width: 100%;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use `[src]="iframeUrl"`as well as bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl

```
this.iframeUrl=this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(...)
```

Comment: you can see src in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-basic-tutorial-rdxcde

Comment: thank you very much! I didn't notice bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl at first so I just used the brackets and that didn't help...